# How can I retrieve all <dependency> in an enforcer custom rule while excluding dependencies declared in a parent pom?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I need to write a custom Maven enforcer rule that makes some checks on all dependencies declared in a `pom.xml` file **but not** in a `<parent>` Maven project. How can I make my custom `EnforcerRule` retrieve all dependencies declared directly and only in my Maven project ?

Example parent `pom.xml`:

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.enforcer</groupId>
            <artifactId>enforcer-api</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.enforcer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

In a child Maven project `a.b.c:child` I have other dependencies, but not `enforcer-api`, I want thus my enforcer plugin to retrieve all dependencies but `enforcer-api`

I tried :

```
MavenProject project = (MavenProject) helper.evaluate("${project}");
List<Dependency> dependencies = project.getDependencies(); 
// dependencies variable includes all dependencies including 
// those declared in parent pom. -> not what I want
```

And :

```
MavenProject project = (MavenProject) helper.evaluate("${project}");
Set<Artifact> dependencies = project.getDependencyArtifacts();
// dependencies variable includes all dependencies including 
// those declared in parent pom. -> not what I want
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Probably a weak solution, but you can retrieve the parent project dependencies through the parent project reference. You already have the child's dependencies that includes that of your parent's. So the common elements between the two sets will tell you what belongs only in the parent, while the difference of two sets will give you the child-only dependencies. Of course all that assuming the `compareTo` and `equals` of the `Dependency`/`Artifact` work as expected.

Comment: Indeed, I thought about this solution as a workaround. Unfortunately doing it this way won't allow me to make some checks.

Comment: The problem seemed to be based on the inheritance where you get the dependency. But the question is why is it a problem to check them, cause they are dependencies too of your project.

Comment: @khmarbaise : to make a long story short, I must make sure that some dependency versions are defined in a single ``pom.xml`` and are not defined or modified in child projects. If parent dependencies are mixed with the ones declared at project level I can't do such checks.

Comment: @mystarrocks : I finally implemented this workaround, it works just fine. However the ``Dependency`` class does not implement ``equals()`` I had thus to do comparison by hand.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the dependencyConvergence rule of maven-enforcer?